# C# SortedDictionary producing unusual results

Tags: c#, sorteddictionary

I'm working with a SortedDictionary where the key is integer and value is string.

```
SortedDictionary<int,string> dic = new SortedDictionary<int,string>();
```

Now say I add values like

```
dic.Add(100,"String 1");
dic.Add(1113,"String 2");
dic.Add(1,"String 3");
dic.Add(70,"String 4");
```

and then do a foreach loop like

```
foreach(string item in dic.Values) {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

then the values never come out in the correct order, they come out in an almost random order which is similar behaviour to a normal Dictionary. Anyone got any ideas why? am I missing / doing something wrong?

PS: When I say it's coming out in a random order I mean key order not value so it's coming out like 1113,70,1,100

---

It seems I may have over simplified the problem, but it shouldn't make a difference, there is a lot of nesting involved and the final dictionary is actually the child of another dictionary which is the child of another!

```
SortedDictionary<String, SortedDictionary<String, SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<String, String>>>>()
```

The dictionary i'm looping through is

```
SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<String, String>>
```

Here is the loop as requested:

```
foreach (SortedDictionary<String, String> cDic in openTrades.Values)
{
    String cTimestamp = convertTimestamp(cDic["open"]);
    if (!closeTrades.ContainsKey(cDic["key"]) && barArray.ContainsKey(cDic["pair"]))
    {
          foreach (SortedDictionary<String, String> bDic in barArray[cDic["pair"]][cDic["frame"]].Values)
          {
               //This is the relative Loop
          }
    }
}
```

barArray is our Primary SortedDictionary (the subject of this question)
openTrades is another SortedDictionary

Thanks
James

Comment: If by "random", you mean you get `String3, String4, String1, String2`, then you are getting the expected behavior.

Comment: Did you ever work out what the problem was here? If so it would be nice to know!

Answer (score 8):

[`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)  sorts on the **key** not the value.

If you do the following

```
foreach(var item in dic)
{
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "-" + item.Value);
}
```

You will see that it prints out in sorted order by key:

```
1-String 3
70-String 4
100-String 1
1113-String 2
```

Comment: Hi, That's what I mean - it's not coming out like that, it's coming out in a random key order

like 1113,70,1,100 there is absolutely no consistency.

Comment: @James: Can you show the *actual* looping code for that final dictionary, something else must be off then.

Comment: i've added it to the end of the question thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you think the output should be, but for me it is

```
String 3
String 4
String 1
String 2
```

Which is correct.  Perhaps you are under the impression that a `SortedDictionary` maintains insertion order?  A quick review of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) will tell you that is not the case.  The values are sorted via a `Comparer<T>` on the key (assuming no custom Comparer is provided.)

Comment: Hi, That's what I mean - it's not coming out like that, it's coming out in a random key order like 1113,70,1,100 there is absolutely no consistency

Answer (score 1):

As all the others my first impression was you are confused if the dictionary is sorted by keys and not by values. But reading your comments this doesn't seem the problem.

So i simply (like the others too) pasted the code into Visual Studio and let it run. The output was (as expected):

```
String 3
String 4
String 1
String 2
```

If the order differs on your machine, there seems to be something really weird going on there. Maybe you can make another run, but make a little change to your foreach statement:

```
foreach (var item in dic)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Now in item you'll get a `KeyValuePair<int, string>`, which will nicely printed out like this:

```
[1, String 3]
[70, String 4]
[100, String 1]
[1113, String 2]
```

So you'll get another check what exact key belongs to each value you got and maybe find another clue why you get a sorting you don't expect.

Comment: Hi, I've addded some more information please take a look I think I was over simplfying the explanation

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The problem lies in your foreach loop. The SortedDictionary class exposes the list of values, but that list isn't sorted, so you are just reading from a unsorted list.</strike>

---

Reading the code again, I realized that the list is being presented in a sorted order. What I think happened is that you got confused because you somehow expected it to sort through the Value field. SortedDictionary sorts through the Key field (the integers in your add statement).

Comment: Hi, That's what I mean - it's not coming out like that, it's coming out in a random key order like 1113,70,1,100 there is absolutely no consistency